# Pass value from text file into a html paragraph

Tags: javascript, html, css, xhtml

I have a text file populated dynamically from another javascript. Owing to require/bundle issues and many, many other problems I am just writing the results to a text file.

I now want to display the results in a paragraph on the webpage. Accessing the info seems straightforward enough, printing to the console works with the below, but how do I now put the text in a paragraph so I can format it with CSS etc:

The text file contains:

```
let text = 'Some random text';
```

And then html file has this in it:

```
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Wallboard</h1>

<script src=output.txt></script>
<script>
let pageText = text;

console.log(pageText)

let myParagraph = document.querySelector("#pageText");

console.log(myParagraph)

myParagraph.innerHTML = pageText;

;
</script>
<p id="pageText"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please edit your question and add in the code segment that demonstrates your best attempt at adding text to the DOM. There are a lot of examples and tutorials on how to do this type of thing...so we need to understand what approach you're taking and what problem or error you've encountered in your attempt. Try googling for something like: how to add text to a DOM element using JavaScript.

Comment: how exactly do you populate `output.txt` from javascript?

Comment: Devlin, bear with me and I will come back to you shortly.

Comment: Grafi, I am using fs.writefile to input the values into the output.txt.

Comment: @devlincarnate I have so far tried the suggestion below from Jarmo. Yes, there seem to be thousands of ways of doing this, which is why I have come here seeking the most efficient way from those who know.

Comment: You may want to [familiarize yourself with the expectations for asking questions on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Basically, it's expected that you're asking a question after you've **exhausted all other efforts**.

Comment: @devlincarnate I understand your position, but I have spent weeks that I don't have working on this for my employer. If I take too much longer on this project then I risk my employment. So I am here seeking answers, and help, and found them. I appreciate it might be thought of as lazy by asking people to do the work for me, but I can assure you I have put the hours into this task and was just looking to save some time by seeking the wisdom of those who know. And I can still learn from the advice given in this way, just faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to find the HTML element with JavaScript and then set the elements inner HTML to be your text content:

```html
</head>
<body>

<script src=output.txt></script>

<p id="pageText"></p>

<script>
let pageText = "Your text here";

let myParagraph = document.querySelector("#pageText");

console.log(myParagraph)

myParagraph.innerHTML = pageText;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am getting the error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')' and when I console log 'myParagraph' it says null.

Comment: Hey, @TheIronKing, would you please provide an example of your current code trying this solution? It sounds to me that you may be running the script before the HTML rendered, so, at that moment, actually the paragraph element doesn't exists.

Comment: Hi Daniel, of course, thank you, I will edit my answer and post above.

Comment: @TheIronKing I forgot to mention, my code example should be placed before the closing </body> tag. I edited the HTML part of my answer to show an example.

Comment: Hi @JarmoT Thank you, I have edited my above code to show my whole body section, your suggestion is before the closing body tag but I am still getting the null value error.

Comment: @TheIronKing Hey, it looks like my edit didn't go through. It should be fixed now and provide a full example. You want to put your JavaScript at the end of the HTML file, because at the start the HTML elements don't exist yet and therefore you can't manipulate them.